# code_challange vs state parameter in OAuth? What is the difference?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect, pkce

I'm trying to understand the difference between `code_challange` and `state` parameter from OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow + PKCE.

I know that `state` parameter is a validation against CSRF attack and is generated (and saved in local storage) on Client (eg. Angular SPA) - and need to be returned from Authorization application in callback after successful login and compared with `state` value saved previously on local storage.

Whereas `code_challange` is generated based on `code_verifier` also genereated and saved in localstorage. So where is the differance with usage?

Also I've noted strange thing - I copied generated auth url which is: `https://APP_ADDRESS.b2clogin.com/APP_ADDRESS.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_signupsignin/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=f9d2b[...]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fauth-callback&response_type=code&scope=f9d2b[...]%20openid&state=31caa207[...]&code_challenge=-MefGRhOo[...]&code_challenge_method=S256&response_mode=query`

And I used that url in different browser. And I was able to login successfuly. I only had an error in console: `No matching state found in storage`. Which make sense since local storage was empty in new browser.

But why there wasn't any error about the `code_challange`? I think it shouldn't be able to login successful, or I miss something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With PKCE, the checks that the **code_challenge** is correct is done on the authentication server-side and the check for valid **state** is done on the client-side.

There are cases where the client does not check the state/nonce properly (or not at all) and we added PKCE to let the auth-server do the check instead. The auth server can force/require that all clients follow the PKCE concept.

Together we get a very strong protection.

The picture below shows how PKCE works

[image]

I recently blogged about the state parameter here:

- [Demystifying OpenID Connect’s State and Nonce Parameters in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/12/13/demystifying-openid-connects-state-and-nonce-parameters-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: But `code_verifier` that is used to validate `code_challange` is generated on client side, right? So if I will use the url from first post on other browser, then I skipped the part where client is sending `code_verifier` to auth server? So how does it work? How auth server can be sure that `code_challange` is valid?

Comment: see my updated answer.The verifier is generated clientside, and the big idea is to verify that the two requests from the client comes from the same instance.  The backend can deny access if the second challenge is not provided. The backend can be sure if the hash of the challenge matches the hash of the first code_challenge

Comment: Any other questions?

Comment: Ok just to sum up: (1) SPA generates `code_verifier` and `code_challange` (and storing `code_verifier` in storage. (2) Calls authenticaion with `code_challange`. (3) User provide login/password. (4) Auth server sending request to Client (using param `redirect_uri`. (5) Client handling that callback and making request to auth server with `code_verifier` from storage. (6) Auth server checks that and if is valid, returns the token. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes! Then the second question is if the SPA should deal with this or you should consider the BFF pattern , see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw